# What is closure and why to use it?

Tags: groovy

What is closure in groovy?

Why we use this closure?

Comment: It seems that you haven't searched well enough, this is the starting point: http://www.groovy-lang.org/closures.html

Comment: Can you please tell me the need of Closure.

Comment: please consult [the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) for the general use of closures.

Comment: @cfrick Should be noted however that Groovy Closures are not strictly Closures ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about Closure annotation parameters?

[...
An interesting feature of annotations in Groovy is that you can use a closure as an annotation value. Therefore annotations may be used with a wide variety of expressions and still have IDE support. For example, imagine a framework where you want to execute some methods based on environmental constraints like the JDK version or the OS. One could write the following code:

```
class Tasks {
    Set result = []
    void alwaysExecuted() {
        result << 1
    }
    @OnlyIf({ jdk>=6 })
    void supportedOnlyInJDK6() {
        result << 'JDK 6'
    }
    @OnlyIf({ jdk>=7 && windows })
    void requiresJDK7AndWindows() {
        result << 'JDK 7 Windows'
    }
}
```

...]
Source:[http://docs.groovy-lang.org/](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_closure_annotation_parameters)

Comment: I don't believe they are

Answer (score 0):

Closures are a powerful concept with which you can implement a variety of things and which enable specifying DSLs. They are sort of like Java ( lambdas, but more powerful and versatile. You dont *need* to use closures, but they can make many things easier.
Since you didnt really specify a concrete question, I'll just point you to the startegy pattern example in the groovy docs:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_strategy_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Think of the closure as an executable unit on its own, like a method or function, except that you can pass it around like a variable, but can do a lot of things that you would normally do with a class, for example.

An example: You have a list of numbers and you either want to add +1 to each number, or you want to double each number, so you say

```
 def nums = [1,2,3,4,5]

 def plusone = { item ->
    item + 1
 }  

 def doubler = { item ->
    item * 2
 }

 println nums.collect(plusone)
 println nums.collect(doubler)
```

This will print out

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

So what you achieved is that you separated the function, the 'what to do' from the object that you did it on. Your closures separate an action that can be passed around and used by other methods, that are compatible with the closure's input and output.

What we did in the example is that we had a list of numbers and we passed each of them to a closure that did something with it. Either added +1 or doubled the value, and collected them into another list.

And this logic opens up a whole lot of possibilities to solve problems smarter, cleaner, and write code that represents the problem better.